# I want to export iframe contents with parent html as pdf from jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, asp-classic, pdf-generation

I had html page with iframes as contents, in iframes, charts are generating.
While genreate pdf with jspdf.js plugin its generating only master html only. jspdf plugin didnt take the iframe contents and didnt apply the css also. how to overcome this issue.
See this below image url
[image]
Thanks in Advance